# Wordpress fails to upload my content

Tags: php, wordpress

I just installed Wordpress on my virtual hosting server and am able to access the admin interface.  I can write posts and make new users, but can't seem to be able to upload images/media.  I keep getting the same error:  “'wrc4.jpg' has failed to upload due to an error"

I have googled this problem and searched through forums, but I can't find a case like mine.

The path that wordpress is attempting to write to is a combination of the absolute path and the virtual path?

```
E:\Sitename\blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03
```

The absolute path that it should write to is:

```
E:\Sitename\blog\wp-content\uploads\2012\03
```

and the virtual path would be:

```
http://sitename.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03
```

How can I change the wordpress settings so I don't receive this error?

Comment: if your hosting is under linux, you must set the proper permissions to upload folder

Comment: I have a Windows server, but I'll check that out

Comment: wow, I feel stupid.  If you submit permissions changing as an answer, I'll mark it correct

Comment: check your error log. `apache2\logs\error.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check your upload's folder permissions, especially the write permission.